# Is it possible to "draw" character in text control with bitmap data?

Tags: unicode, bitmap

There is some legacy 16x16 bitmap lattice data, which were used to display some user-defined non-common Japanese characters, so there is little chance to get corresponding text through OCR.

And due to some weird reason, it is impossible to add a bitmap control to our product. But display them using a text control with Unicode support is somehow acceptable.

So is it possible to draw such bitmap within text conotrol?

I have heard Unicode has some control character, but not sure if they can save me from this..

Comment: You might be able to do this by converting the bitmap to a custom font and creating an alphabet in the [private range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Private_use_characters).

Comment: What programming environment are you using? Windows32? .Net? Linux? JavaScript in a browser? And what text control are you using? There isn't enough information in your question.